# T-SQL - Copying & Transposing Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to copy data from one table to another, while transposing it and combining it into appropriate rows, with different columns in the second table.

First time posting.  Yes this may seem simple to everyone here.  I have tried for a couple hours to solve this. I do not have much support internally and have learned a great deal on this forum and managed to get so much accomplished with your other help examples.  I appreciate any help with this.

Table 1 has the data in this format.

```
Type    Date  Value
--------------------
First   2019  1
First   2020  2
Second  2019  3
Second  2020  4
```

Table 2 already has the Date rows populated and columns created.  It is waiting for the Values from Table 1 to be placed in the appropriate column/row.

```
Date  First Second
------------------
2019    1     3
2020    2     4
```

Comment: You can use string_agg function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an update, I might use two `join`s:

```
update  t2
    set first = tf.value,
        second = ts.value
    from table2 t2 left join
         table1 tf
         on t2.date = tf.date and tf.type = 'First' left join
         table1 ts
         on t2.date = ts.date and ts.type = 'Second'
    where tf.date is not null or ts.date is not null;
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank you very much.  I gave an up vote but I'm too new for it to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select date, 
       max(case when type = 'first' then value end) as first,
       max(case when type = 'Second' then value end) as Second
from table t
group by date;
```

After that you can use `cte` :

```
with cte as (
     select date, 
            max(case when type = 'first' then value end) as first,
            max(case when type = 'Second' then value end) as Second
     from table t
     group by date
)

update t2
      set t2.First = t1.First,
          t2.Second = t1.Second
from table2 t2 inner join
     cte t1
     on t1.date = t2.date;
```

Comment: This also worked.  Thank you very much.  I gave an up vote but I'm too new for it to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

use  conditional aggregation

```
select date,max(case when type='First' then value end) as First,
       max(case when type='Second' then value end) as Second  from t
   group by date
```

Comment: is this same as what pivot does @Zaymul

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're after a [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

```
 DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
    (
        [Type] NVARCHAR(100)
      , [Date] INT
      , [Value] INT
    );

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(
[Date] int
,[First] int
,[Second] int
)

INSERT INTO @Table1 (
                          [Type]
                        , [Date]
                        , [Value]
                      )
VALUES ( 'First', 2019, 1 )
     , ( 'First', 2020, 2 )
     , ( 'Second', 2019, 3 )
     , ( 'Second', 2020, 4 );

INSERT INTO @Table2 (
                        [Date]
                    )
VALUES (2019),(2020)

--Show us what's in the tables
SELECT * FROM @Table1
SELECT * FROM @Table2

--How to pivot the data from Table 1 
SELECT * FROM   @Table1
    PIVOT (
              MAX([Value]) --Pivot on this Column
              FOR [Type] IN ( [First], [Second] ) --Make column where [Value] is in one of this
          ) AS [pvt] --Table alias

--which gives
--Date        First       Second
------------- ----------- -----------
--2019        1           3
--2020        2           4

--Using that we can update @Table2
UPDATE [tbl2]
SET [tbl2].[First] = pvt.[First]
    ,[tbl2].[Second] = pvt.[Second]
FROM   @Table1 tbl1
    PIVOT (
              MAX([Value]) --Pivot on this Column
              FOR [Type] IN ( [First], [Second] ) --Make column where [Value] is in one of this
          ) AS [pvt] --Table alias
INNER JOIN @Table2 tbl2 ON [tbl2].[Date] = [pvt].[Date]

--Results from @Table 2 after updated
SELECT * FROM @Table2

--which gives
--Date        First       Second
------------- ----------- -----------
--2019        1           3
--2020        2           4
```

Comment: This worked and it was an incredible explanation.  Thank you very much.  I gave an up vote but I'm too new for it to be visible.

Comment: @MichaelStewart  You're welcome.  Just choose the answer that you think is best and accept it, check mark next to the answer. The OP can always accept an answer, regardless of reputation.